# Как скачать таблицу из юпитер ноутбука?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, таблицы

Предположим, что у меня есть таблица в формате dataframe, я преобразую её в формат csv, используя to_csv, как теперь мне скачать эту таблицу?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разберем на примере кода:

```
import pandas as pd
cities = pd.DataFrame([['Sacramento', 'California'], ['Miami', 'Florida']], columns=['City', 'State'])
cities.to_csv('cities.csv')
```

В строке `cities.to_csv('cities.csv')` вы конвертирует DataFrame-файл и записываете в файл 'cities.csv',  также можно указать прямой путь к файлу. Далее он сохраняется в рабочем каталоге запущенного файла. Следовательно, вам не надо будет скачивать сам конвертированный файл,он будет в той же директории, где находится ваш py-файл с кодом выше(если брать пример выше).